# Mailcore2-iOS - Shell Script Invocation Error

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, mailcore, mailcore2

I am getting a "Shell script invocation error" when I try to build my application using Xcode 5.1. The specific error I am getting is "Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1". I have dug around Google, but none of the fixes are working for me. In the Frameworks section of Xcode, libMailCore.a and libMailCore-iOS.a are both red. MailCore.framework is red as well. I have downloaded the latest mailcore code and followed the tutorial on installing it on for iOS. I have command line tools installed, and dragged the xcode project mailcore2 into xcode. Is there something I am doing wrong in this process?

This is the error log:

```
    /bin/sh -c \"/Users/Prajoth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Screensaver-adwouweiqurmflesjnwbyukhfjmm/Build/Intermediates/mailcore2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/static\ mailcore2\ ios.build/Script-C6BA2B0A1705F4E6003F0E9E.sh\"

SDK not found
SDK not found
SDK not found
SDK not found
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Could you update to Xcode5.1? Could you try to remove the mailcore2/Externals folders and retry the build? The first build should take some time.

Comment: I am currently running 5.1 and I did try removing the Externals folder but that did not work.

Comment: did you fix this error ?

Comment: @Ramz I was having the same issue. I updated my copy of mailcore2 to the latest and it fixed it.

Comment: Yes I too did the same and again I had to update mailcore2 for xcode 6.1 with Yosemite update